# No point cloud in Turtlebot Gazebo gmapping

Tags: gazebo, navigation, kinect, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow this tutorial with Gazebo simulator:

http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/11/

In the tutorial, (real) Turtlebot is scanning the environment with Kinect point cloud. But when I run the examples in the **turtlebot_gazebo** package, it only scans with a fake laser. Probably because of this node, in the launch file of example:

https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/blob/indigo/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/turtlebot_world.launch#L25

Anyway, how can I add the Kinect point cloud scan to that example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204280/no-point-cloud-in-turtlebot-gazebo-gmapping/) by [Ahmet Sezgin Duran](https://answers.ros.org/users/21727/ahmet-sezgin-duran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can see the point cloud if you add PointCloud2 with the topic name: e.g. /camera/depth/points

---

Originally posted by [JollyGood](https://answers.ros.org/users/985/jollygood/) with karma: 58 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmet Sezgin Duran](https://answers.ros.org/users/21727/ahmet-sezgin-duran/) on 2015-03-08**:
Anyway without using script? I just wanted to see it in Rviz.

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2015-03-11**:
In RViz, you add a visualization by clicking the "add" button on the bottom left. A window will pop up, displaying different data types. Click "PointCloud2", hit "OK", and you will see a PointCloud2 on the left-hand side of RViz in the "Displays" area. Expand it, and then type the topic in.